# Python Perfect Square

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that takes a list L as a parameter and returns a list consisting of all the elements in L that are perfect squares.

```
def isPerfectSquare(n):

    return n==int(math.sqrt(n))**2


def perfectSquares2(L):

    import math
    return(list(filter(isPerfectSquare,(L))))
```

I think my filter function is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it...

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: `math.sqrt` is approximate, so that square check will fail when you hit floating-point precision limits.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `import math` in `isPerfectSquare`, otherwise it is just imported in the local scope of the `perfetSquares2` function.

However, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) suggests you put module imports at the top of scripts:

```
import math
def isPerfectSquare(n):
    return n==int(math.sqrt(n))**2

def perfectSquares2(L):
    return(list(filter(isPerfectSquare,(L))))
```

---

By the way, I think a list comprehension may be faster here:

```
def perfectSquares2(L):
    return [i for i in L if isPerfectSquare(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use `lambda`. Also, no need to use `list()` if Python 2.x or the extra parens.

```
import math
def perfectSquares2(L):
    return filter(lambda n: n==int(math.sqrt(n))**2, L)
```

Comment: In Python 3, `filter` doesn't return a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input())
if x>0:
    for i in range(x):
        p=i**2
        print(p)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!